# Select value of selectbox, get row from MYSQL and work with result in one file

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have selectbox populate from mysql and I want when I select value of selectbox go to mysql table with ajax get the value of one column by selected value of selectbox and use it in same file...

How its possible? Thanks

***index.php***

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="l">
        Štát:
    </div>
    <div class="r">
        <select name="country_" id="country_">
            <?php   
                echo '<option value="0">Zvoľte ... </option>';
                    $query = 'SELECT * FROM postovne';
                    $result = mysql_query($query);
                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                            $idC = $row['id'];
                            $land = $row['land'];
                            $priceD = $row['dobierka'];
                            $priceU = $row['ucet'];
                                if ($idC == 1) {
                                    echo '<option value="'.$idC.'" selected>'.$land.'</option>';
                                } else {
                                    echo '<option value="'.$idC.'">'.$land.'</option>';
                                }
                         }
            ?>
        </select>

    </div>
</div>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
         //some AJAX function
</script>

<div class="a">
     <div class="l">
       Cena:
     </div>
     <div class="r">
        <?php echo $priceD; ?>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Whenever you use PHP's deprecated mysql_ API, a kitten dies. Or so I'm told.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at my question, didnt work for me on wordpress for still mysterious reasons, but it should work, also check out the chat session in that question:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/43800131/7862006
And indeed its not a get your free custom made script site over here, go do some research and try, when you fail (many times) give us an overview and perhaps we can help you get on the right track.